# C# Chatroom message order with same timestamp

Tags: c#, multithreading, datetime, timestamp

I'm making a server which can receive messages from different clients at the same time.

Each message sent includes, Username, Message, and Timestamp.

Since the server is multi-threaded, the timestamp i get by using 
`Datetime timeStamp = Datetime.Now;` might have the same value in a very tiny chance.

Clients can't order the messages with the same timestamp, and may cause ordering problem.

So I'm thinking is there a method that can get the current time with milliseconds which is accurate enough to avoid the timeStamp conflict?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What conflict?   If you store them in a database, you can make the timestamp a _non-unique_ index and there will be no problem.

Comment: @SteveWellens but the message sent to the clients will have the same timestamp. May cause Client1 get msgA then msgB, and Client2 get msgB first.

Comment: So?   They will be so close it doesn't matter.  Network latency can cause messages to be slightly 'out-of-order'.   Sometimes people  send messages at exactly the same time.   It happens here too when people make comments at the exact same time.

Comment: But if we comment at the exact same time, SO still makes an order to the 2 comments.

Comment: @SteveWellens Like Skype or Facebook, if 2 people comment at the same time, the order is still given. I'm thinking is there a way to achieve that.

Comment: If there are two comments at exactly the same time, which one should be first?    It doesn't matter.   They will be adjacent in time.

Answer (score 0):

From the user point of view, it does not matter, what is the actual order of two messages that were send in the roughly same time. This is because there are many factors including network latency that prevent you to easily determine an "absolute order" of the messages.

This means that you can introduce ANY ordering you like that will achieve that. If you use a database and put your messages there, you can simply use the lower database ID, as a sign, which message came first. But you can really use any other thing. You can generate a random number that is long enough to be unique with enough probability and send it with your timestamp and then use it as the second value to determine the order.